# Python3 : EOF Error while taking input on GUVI

Tags: python, python-3.x, priority-queue, eof

This is my code in python3:

```
import heapq

myQueue = []
n = raw_input()
try:
  num = int(n)
  if num<=100000 :
    arr = input().split()
  for i in range(num):
    heapq.heappush(myQueue, arr[i])
    print(myQueue[0])

except (NameError, ValueError):
  print("Wrong Input, N should be under 100000")

except IndexError:
  print("Inputs is less than actually required")

except EOFError:
  print ("Error: EOF or empty input!")
```

I am trying to implement priority queue.
But I am facing this EOF Error while solving this problem on GUVI.

```
Output:
Error: EOF or empty input!
```

The tried to catch the error using except EOFError, but that will just make my program run but does not solve input problem right.
I even tried to run this piece of code on *Sublime text* editor as well as *Vs code*,
where it runs just fine, Correct Output.
I don't understand, is there a problem in my code or That Online Platform.
I even tried to search the answer on their Q&A platform of GUVI, I found similar question but no one has answered it.
And this is not just for this piece of Code but I found the same error for many before.

**Could ANYONE help me, Please!**

*Thanking you in advance.. :)*

Answer (score 1):

EOF error occurs if the input is not provided.

In case of most of the online compilers you need to provide the inputs before running the code.

With that said, while your are trying to access the input via raw_input() there will be no input supplied resulting in the above error.

To avoid this, error supply inputs before running your code like below

[image]

Also, I can notice that you are using raw_input() and input(). Please note that raw_input() can be used if you are using Python 2 and input() if you are using python 3 correspondingly.